# Getting list of SMS and MMS messages in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms, mms

Does any one know if it is possible to get the list of SMS/MMS messages in windows phone 7?
Is it possible to modify/delete SMS messages?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of the platform does not allow an application to enumerate of change/delete messages.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks.